# parsing dynamic background image to dynamic html elements

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Im trying to parse a background image to html elements. The background images are taken from a database and the html elements are created dynamically. Problem is the image does not show. So I decided to include a javascript in the while loop. I get a token error. I need some help here please. Thanks.I just need the javascript to be fixed.

```
           $p_name = $row['product_name'];
           $p_price = $row['product_price'];
           $p_desc = $row['product_description'];
           $p_image = $row['product_image1_url'];
           $p_id = $row['product_id'];
           $b_id = $row['business_id'];
           $bg_image = "backend/$p_image";
           $return.= "<div class = 'dashboard-main-product-view-card'>
                           <div class = 'product-wrapper-image-i' data-background = \"$bg_image\"
                           ' id = 'productimage$p_id'>
                               <script type = 'text/javascript'>
                                   var obj = $('#productimage".$p_id."').css('background-image', \"url('".$bg_image."')\");

                               </script>
                           </div>
                           <div class=\"product-wrapper\">
                           <h2 id=\"product-view-price\">$p_price</h2>
                           <p id=\"product-view-name\">$p_name</p>
                           <p id=\"product-view-description\">$p_desc</p>
                       </div>

           </div>";
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need js to add a background image when you are already in controll of the DOM.

You can just add it as an inline style like this:

```php
"
…
  <div class='product-wrapper-image-i' style='background-image: url($bg_image);'>
    …
  </div>
…
"
```

Comment: yes, this technique is not not working. It keeps showing undefined whenever I inspect the element as the image is not displaying. Again, this is my code;

Comment: ```  
            $p_image = $row['product_image1_url'];
            $bg_image = "backend/".$p_image;
            $return.= "<div class = 'dashboard-main-product-view-card'>
                            <div class = 'product-wrapper-image-i' 
                            style = 'background-image: url($bg_image);' id = 'productimage$p_id'>
                           </div>
           
                        </div>
            
            </div>";```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the background image…
Maybe the $bg_image varaible is undefined or the url is wrong or something else…